# Increase the Background behind a grid

Tags: list-manipulation

This create a nice table

```
 Grid[{{" i/j", Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[a, 3], 
 Subscript[a, 4], Subscript[a, 5]}, {" Mal-Représentation", 0, 1, 
 2, 3, 4 }}, Background -> LightYellow, 
 Dividers -> {{2 -> Red}, {2 -> Red}}, Spacings -> {1, 1}]
```

but I would like a little space after the last item or that the background be a little more greater than the table. I see nothing in the options of `Grid` which permit this and the space before i/j does not work  after 4 because 4 is not a string. So is it possible to have a greater background?

Answer (score 4):

But you can always insert empty strings to extend the grid. How about this:

```
Grid[
  {{"", "i/j", Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[a, 3], 
    Subscript[a, 4], Subscript[a, 5], ""},
   {"", "Mal-Représentation", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ""}},
  Background -> LightYellow,
  Dividers -> {{3 -> Red}, {2 -> Red}},
  Spacings -> {1, 1}]
```

[image: grid]

#### Update

Perhaps put it on a panel?

```
Panel[
  Grid[
    {{"", "i/j", Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[a, 3], 
      Subscript[a, 4], Subscript[a, 5], ""}, 
     {"", "Mal-Représentation", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ""}},
    Background -> LightYellow,
    Dividers -> {{3 -> Red}, {2 -> Red}},
    Spacings -> {1, 1}],
  Background -> LightYellow,
  FrameMargins -> Medium]
```

You can adjust the frame margins to your liking.

[image: A]

Comment: For one time I have found this by myself. My problem is above and under and not to have the line reaching the borders

Answer (score 0):

**RE: *I see nothing in the options of Grid which permit this***

It is not in the `Grid` page but there is an example in the `Spacings` page:

[Documentation >> Spacings >> Last example](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Spacings.html):

- *Set the size of the grid's margins:*

Slightly modified to make the differences visible:

```
Framed@Grid[Table[x, {3}, {7}], Spacings -> {{5, {}, 5}, {5, {}, 5}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

However, without the option `Frame -> True` the margins are, somehow, invisible:

[image]

So, in your example you can use `Spacings -> {{2, {1}, 2}, 1}` and set the `FrameStyle` and `Background` to the same color to get:

```
Grid[{{" i/j", Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[a, 3], 
   Subscript[a, 4], Subscript[a, 5]}, {"Mal-Représentation", 0, 1, 2,
    3, 4}}, Background -> LightYellow, 
 Dividers -> {2 -> Red, 2 -> Red}, Spacings -> {{2, {1}, 2}, 1}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> LightYellow]
```

[image]

**Update:** For the requirement

> ***not to have the line reaching the borders***

added in the comments, you can use `Panel` as m_goldberg's answer or `Framed` and set the `FrameMargins` as you like:

```
Framed[Grid[{{" i/j", Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2], 
    Subscript[a, 3], Subscript[a, 4], 
    Subscript[a, 5]}, {"Mal-Représentation", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}}, 
  Background -> LightYellow, Dividers -> {2 -> Red, 2 -> Red}, 
  Spacings -> {1, 1}], FrameMargins -> {{10, 10}, {5, 5}}, 
 FrameStyle -> LightYellow, Background -> LightYellow]
```

[image]